# Why are Footer's contents not adjacant to each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a footer in a website which has 2 section of links, I want them adjacent to each other in xl, lg, md screens and want it to stack over each other when in sm and xs screens. I am using bootstrap, bulma and tailwind. My code is as follows:
Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Do+Hyeon&family=Dosis:wght@400;500&family=East+Sea+Dokdo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\bulma\bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\tailwind\tailwind.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\styles.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<footer class="container" id="footer">
        <div class="flex-auto">
            <div class="flex-auto col-sm"> 
                <div class="footer-heading">Visit our webpages</div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> C Programming</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Visual Basic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Java</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Python</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr class=".d-block .d-sm-none">
            <div class="flex-auto col-sm"> 
                <div class="footer-heading">Contact Us</div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Youtube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Business Inquiries</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> LinkedIn</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Skype</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Discord</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-extra-text">
            <div>Made with love by <span class="kavya-production">Kavya's Production</span></div>
            <br>
            <div>&copy;Copywright <span class="kavya-production">Kavya's Production</span> 2020</div>
        </div>
</footer>

<!--- End of Footer --->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script scr="..\script.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
```

CSS Code:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #3d453f;
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.footer-heading, #footer-extra-text {
    color: #fff;
}

#footer-extra-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-links {
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #4fd929, #4fd929 50%, #d7f20a 50%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: 100%;
    transition: background-position 275ms ease;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links:hover {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

Codepen is as follows: https://codepen.io/Kav_Sharma/pen/xxEgGKg
Thank You in advance for the answers

Comment: KIndly Check the answer, That I have provided. This works in all the cases. Do please accept the answer by clicking on the tick icon and also rate by clicking on the up triangle, since this is the solution to the problem :) Thanks and Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the HTML codes. col-md-6 important

```
<footer class="container" id="footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                <div class="footer-heading">Visit our webpages</div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> C Programming</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Visual Basic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Java</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Python</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr class="d-block d-md-none">
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                <div class="footer-heading">Contact Us</div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Youtube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Business Inquiries</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> LinkedIn</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Skype</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Discord</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-extra-text">
            <div>Made with love by <span class="kavya-production">Kavya's Production</span></div>
            <br>
            <div>&copy;Copywright <span class="kavya-production">Kavya's Production</span> 2020</div>
        </div>
</footer>

<!--- End of Footer --->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script scr="..\script.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS Media Query and this will work fine:

```
@media (min-width:768px){
   #footer-extra-text{
     display:flex !important;
     justify-content:center;
     flex-direction:row;
   }
   #footer-extra-text div:first-child{
      margin-right:1rem; /* just to set a small margin */
   }
}
```

**FULL WORKING CODE:**

```css
#footer {
    background-color: #3d453f;
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.footer-heading, #footer-extra-text {
    color: #fff;
}

#footer-extra-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-links {
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #4fd929, #4fd929 50%, #d7f20a 50%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: 100%;
    transition: background-position 275ms ease;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links:hover {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}

@media (min-width:768px){
  #footer-extra-text{
    display:flex !important;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:row;
  }
  #footer-extra-text div:first-child{
    margin-right:1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Do+Hyeon&family=Dosis:wght@400;500&family=East+Sea+Dokdo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\bulma\bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\tailwind\tailwind.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\styles.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<footer class="container" id="footer">
        <div class="flex-auto">
            <div class="flex-auto col-sm"> 
                <div class="footer-heading">Visit our webpages</div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> C Programming</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Visual Basic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Java</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Python</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr class=".d-block .d-sm-none">
            <div class="flex-auto col-sm"> 
                <div class="footer-heading">Contact Us</div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Youtube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Business Inquiries</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> LinkedIn</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Skype</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Discord</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-extra-text">
            <div>Made with love by <span class="kavya-production">Kavya's Production</span></div>
        
            <div>&copy;Copywright <span class="kavya-production">Kavya's Production</span> 2020</div>
        </div>
</footer>

<!--- End of Footer --->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script scr="..\script.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
```